# Make changes to c# program without loosing older code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm a hobbyist programmer and I've created an application for my office. Every so often I need to improve the code, add features or fix issues that come up under certain circumstances - I've found bugs or ineffective coding even after 3-4 months of heavy usage of the application. The thing is that whenever I modify the code, visual studio saves the changes. This means that if I want to use the program I'll have to be really fast in coding and debugging or it won't build - and I won't be able to use it...
Is there any way to keep the old version of the program without having to save the complete project folder elsewhere? Like creating a new version but keeping the option to go back to the old - working - one...

Comment: you want to use a source code repository such as TFS, Mercurial, Subversion, Git, etc. It will allow you to store every revision you make to your code base.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management).

There are many systems out there, two popular ones are [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) and [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

Used properly, you will have a full history of each file you have in your project.

Comment: Or TFS which is free hosted for 5 users. NOONE EVER should work without version control.

Comment: I once saw someone who had a really good argument against source control. Ironically they accidentally saved over it and lost it all.

Comment: @RhysW Nice one. I laughed.

Comment: This one seems to be the most useful answer because it mentions Git which seems to be just what I needed. Thanks to everybody though. StackOverflow is awesome...

Answer (score 3):

There are two other answers here regarding source control at the time I write this, but there is another angle on this as well.

You're executing your *production* copy from the *development* directory. Don't do this.

When you have developed the program to a stable version, make a copy of it somewhere else and use that copy. In this way you're free to keep developing on the software without destroying your ability to keep using the existing stable version.

As for source control, you should definitely use that as well if you're not already doing it. It would, among other things, allow you to go back and hotfix the stable version with minor bugfixes while still doing major rewrites of the software, as well as the features others here have mentioned, full history of your project, "unlimited" undo, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean that Visual Studio saves the code when you modify it. It does by default save when you build, but I don't think it saves while you're typing.

Anyway, what you're looking for is called a **source control** system.

Comment: When you build and run a program in VS it auto saves any changes. It has to, because it runs from the local file when running, not from the visual studio copy, so it auto saves on build, and runs that so that your changes take effect

Comment: Yes, I know that. It's just the part about being "fast in coding" that confused me.

Comment: Yeah i agree, i got totally lost there too... and the reason why i explained it is because originally you said if you werent sure if it did or not

Answer (score 1):

You can try Team Foundation Service from Microsoft.

It works fine and you can share youre project whit colleagues.

http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

EDIT:
This is a free of charge option you can use, until you want to share youre project with more than 4 persons!! than you have to pay for TFS

Comment: With up to 4 colleagues, before you have to pay

Comment: thats right, but as i see he don't even need to share it whit one colleague :P

Comment: he is not the only person who might look at this answer when looking for help. This is after all a help site, and its important to mention somethings limitations to allow people to make an informed decision

Comment: Will you clarify this for me please? Do I have to invite other people? I don't want to do that... Do I have to pay from the start or after some trial time?

Comment: you only have to pay if you have more then 5 users on TFS, so for you, it is free of charge (beside beer you will send to Apero for an answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need source control.

If your project is open source you can use [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/), it's an open-source Website where engineers and computer scientists share projects and ideas. Its features include wiki pages, source control based on Mercurial, Team Foundation Server or Subversion (also powered by TFS), Git,discussion forums, issue tracking, project tagging, RSS support, statistics, and releases

If you don't want to share your code you can use [Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx)